# Why does my inbox say I have two answers and I can only see one?

Tags: discussion

I came in this am to an email saying I had an additional answer to my question [How to host WCF Data Service in ASP.Net MVC3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682654/how-to-host-wcf-data-service-in-asp-net-mvc3-ap)p
that looked as if it might be what I was looking for. However, when I go to my inbox or the thread itself I only see the previous answer. Whay might this be? Was the answer deleted for some reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another answer was posted, but was subsequently deleted. Your inbox items do not clear when the posts to which they refer are deleted.

You aren't missing anything; the basic answer is the same as the other one. The person who posted the second seems to have realized it was essentially the same, and so removed it.